# Copy string into array

Tags: c

I am trying to copy the characters of a string into a dynamic array. Here's what I'm working with:

```
void foo(const char * string, char ** final)
{
    unsigned long n = strlen(string);
    final = (char **)malloc(n+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        final[i] = string[i];  // error here
    }
}
```

The build is failing and pointing to the line marked "error here." With the error:

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'const char.'
```

I think the problem is when I created the array / getting the pointers correct.

Comment: `result` is undeclared.

Comment: What error does the compiler give you?

Comment: Please learn to think like a programmer: Don't say _error here_. Explain all the details you have so far about the error. And then look for more details. I can see you have a compile error but, good grief; how is _error here_ helpful?

Comment: *The build is failing* is absolutely meaningless. (So is using a variable you've not defined and not being able to see that before posting here.) When the build *fails*, you get an error message that tells you why. It's on the screen in front of you. There is absolutely no excuse for failing to include that error message in your question. You're asking us for **free help** solving **your problem**; you should include the information you already have available to make it as easy as possible for us to do so. Especially when that information is **on your screen**, right in front of you.

Comment: I suppose the error is something like "Making pointer from integer without a cast"?

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally wrote "result" instead of "final." The error message is "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'const char.'

Comment: *The error message is "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'const char.'*   That's because, with `final` defined as a `char **`, `final[i]` is a `char *`.  It'd be a lot easier to just *return* the pointer instead of trying to modify the content of a pointer passed by address:  `char *foo( const char *str ) { char *final = malloc( strlen( str ) + 1 ); strcpy( final, str ); return( final );}`.  That would also be known as [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `final` is your output parameter, youll need to dereference it to assign the result of malloc, then again for the assignment in the loop

```
*final = malloc(n+1);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    (*final)[i] = string[i];
}
```

Again this is assuming your intended usage is something like the following

```
input_str = "some text";
char* copy;
foo(input_str, &copy);
```

Though it begs the question why not make the api return the copy?

```
char* copy = foo(input_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code wouldn't really work if a NULL handle (pointer to a pointer) is being passed by reference. So it wouldn't make much sense to do all the allocation business inside foo(): if foo() doesn't return ***final***, it is not usable outside foo() unless already initialized, IMHO. Then the handle would make sense, foo() takes the address of the second string as argument and does not have to return it. Let's consider this example code, based on the original post (debug prints included):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(const char * string, char ** final)
{
(*final) = (char *)malloc(n+1);//we deference the address to reach and size the variable
printf("From foo:  ");
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i)
{
    (*final)[i] = string[i];  
    printf("%c",(*final)[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Let's suppose foo() being called from another function in the following way, for simplicity:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
char  *fin;
char  *str = "string";
foo(str, &fin);    
printf("From main: ");
for(unsigned long j = 0; j < strlen(fin); j++)
    printf("%c", fin[j]);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

It would work, but what for? There are simpler means of achieving the same result, IMHO. Hope this can help.